# How to implement an offline first approach with Cosmos DB in combination with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, azure-cosmosdb, offline

I am building an app with Xamarin Forms and want to use Cosmos DB. Matt Soucoup has a very nice serie (Partly Cloudy) in which he uses AppCenter Data to accomplish this but unfortuanetly this option (together with the Auth option) has bene retired. 
What would be the best option to implement Offline first for Xamarin/Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 1):

For Cosmos DB SQL API, you will have to build your own implementation as there is nothing on the severe side or on the client side SDKs to provide the scaffolding to make this easy. There is a user voice for this capability:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6642530-offline-version-for-mobile-devices

Comment: Just discovered MonkeyCatch: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/monkey-cache

Do you think that it is the solution we are looking for?